# ArgumentCaptor and comparing with hasItems

Tags: java, mockito, hamcrest

i am already desperate, i cannot find out why this test is not evaluated as successful. I have checked it milion times:

```
package someptest;
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;
import static org.mockito.Matchers.any;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.List;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.ArgumentCaptor;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import somep.Order;
import somepBO.BOException;
import somepdao.OrderDAO;

public class XXX {

@Mock
OrderDAO dao;

@Before
public void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}

@Test
public void captor_A() throws SQLException, BOException {
    Order order = new Order();
    ArgumentCaptor<Integer> intCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Integer.class);
    when(dao.read(any(Integer.class))).thenReturn(order);
    dao.read(123);
    dao.read(456);
    verify(dao, times(2)).read(intCaptor.capture());
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    List<Integer> xs = intCaptor.getAllValues();
    assertThat(intCaptor.getAllValues(), hasItems(456));
}
}
```

Here is a screen from my debugging, captor catches correct values, but assertThat does not accept it, why?

[image]

Comment: try `hasItems(Integer.valuef(456))`

Comment: Does not work:
assertThat(intCaptor.getAllValues(), hasItems(Integer.valueOf(456)));

Comment: Your NoSuchMethodError suggests you have some incompatability in the JAR files you're using.  What versions of the JUnit, Hamcrest and Mockito JARs do you have?

Comment: JUnit 4.12, mockito 1.10.19, hamcrest 1.3.

Comment: now it works i imported newer mockito and its three dependencies, that was the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phew, something seems to go quite wrong on your machine. Based on your test, I created the following self-contained test class:

```
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.ArgumentCaptor;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;

import java.util.List;

import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.hasItems;
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

public class ArgumentCaptorTest {

    private static class Order {
    }

    public static class OrderDAO {
        public Order read(Integer any) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Mock
    OrderDAO dao;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void captor_A() {
        Order order = new Order();
        ArgumentCaptor<Integer> intCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Integer.class);
        when(dao.read(any(Integer.class))).thenReturn(order);
        dao.read(123);
        dao.read(456);
        verify(dao, times(2)).read(intCaptor.capture());
        assertThat(intCaptor.getAllValues(), hasItems(456));
    }
}
```

Used dependencies (pom.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>testing</groupId>
    <artifactId>testing</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.18.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

When I start the test, it runs perfectly and gives me a green bar. For what I see, you're doing it right. Maybe you have version conflicts between JUnit, Hamcrest and Mockito that lead to your error? I used these JAR versions:

- junit:junit:4.12
- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3
- org.mockito:mockito-core:2.18.3

I also left the imports so you can compare them with yours (just in case that a "wrong" import causes the error). As you statically import `Matchers.*` from the Hamcrest package, I am quite sure that this and/or your used library versions cause your problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot, my mockito jar was outdated (below 2) and i did not import its three dependency jars. I used your imports, now it works fine :-)